# Remove an option from a Visual force SelectList SelectOption

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I have a VisualForce page where I am using SelectList and SelectOption.
For example if my SelectOption list contians 
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3

I need to remove Option 2 on the page by its value not by index.
I can add validation in my controller, but I wanted to do it on the page since I plan on reusing the selectlist.

```
<apex:selectList id="recordTypeSelect" value="{!currentCaseObject.RecordTypeId}"  >
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!newVisaTypesList}" id="visaoptionid"/>                                                                                                                      
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: You can add logic in the controller in the get method of your list

Comment: Why don't you just build the list without that value in the first place?

Comment: I am not adding the values in the list manually. They come from a query.
They are different for different times. But I want to be able to remove specific values. Not from the controller but from the page

Comment: Any reasons behind this kind of design? What are the benefits of doing this, which can be better be maintained at controller

Comment: If it's action in the page (e.g. pressing button or selecting other value) it can invoke function in the controller that will reset the selection option list similarity to the code I added... . I'm not sure if it's possible only from the page without invoking the controller. Assume anything is possible but you will need to store/populate the values in other way instead of  list variable in the controller.

Comment: I found a way to do that. Have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried this in the page and it worked.

```
<script>
var x= document.getElementById("page:inputForm:recordTypeSelect");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
if(x.options[i].text == 'Value to be removed')
    x.remove(i);
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic in the controller in the get method of your list .

e.g.

```
public List<SelectOption> newVisaTypesList{
    get 
    {
       list<SelectOption> pOptions = new list<SelectOption>();  
    if(condition)
        pOptions.add(new SelectOption('1', '1')); 
    if(condition)
            pOptions.add(new SelectOption('2', '2')); 
        return pOptions;          
    }
    set;
    }
```

Comment: I want to do that on page itself without disturbing the controller.